# C++ assignment works with deleted assignment operator?

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that looks something like this:

```
class B
{
private:
    const A& obj;
    size_t val;

    // private - prohibited
    B& operator=(const B& other);

public:
    B(const A& obj_): obj(obj_)
    {
        val = 0;
    }
};

class C
{
    void func()
    {
        A a1;
        B b1(a1);
        B b2 = b1; // should throw error?
    }
}
```

`Class B` has a private assignment operator. Nonetheless assignment in `C::func()` compiles without errors. But how?

Comment: The compiler could be seeing that b1 is never used again, and instead using the public default move operator. Try setting the move operator to private and see if this happens.

Comment: Assignment can only occur to an object that already exists. Here, `b2` is a new object so it's being constructed.

Comment: @John That's not how it works. Optimizations do not allow the compiler to ignore the language rules. To be used with the move constructor, objects need to be actual temporaries according to the language, not just their usage.

Comment: @John No need to guess. It's copy *initialization*, no assignment operator involved at all.

Comment: Regarding title: Deleting an assignment operator is different thing from declaring it private. As such, the title is highly misleading.

Comment: @errorika not that it changes the substance of the issue. While the two are different, you'd expect the same, or at least similar behavior.

Comment: `B b2 = b1;` looks like an assignment but is not, it's only uses a constructor. This can be confusing when first encountered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B b2 = b1` does not use the assignment operator, because it's not *assignment*, it's *copy initialization* - using constructor, not assignment operator.

See also [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Answer (score 2):

That's the copy constructor getting called, not the assignment operator.

The reason being is that when you initialize a variable, a constructor (in this case, the copy constructor) gets called.

```
B b2 = b1; // construction
```

This is different from assignment

```
b2 = b1; // b2 is already declared, so assignment
```

To stop this behavior, just delete your copy constructor.

Comment: Instead of making the copy constructor private, it would be better to delete it if your intention is to make the class non-copy-constructible. It will better show intent in the code and compiler errors.